# Pandas dataframe - count the sum of rows up to the condition and compare it with the list elements

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data example:

```
           0         1         2         3        
2  Text1   1         1         5         5,00       
3  Text2   8         4         0         0,00     
4  Text3   1         3         0         2,00     
5  SUM     6         0         0         7,00       
6  Text1   1         1         0         10        
7  Text2   8         4         0         0,00     
8  Text3   1         3         0         0,00
8  Text4   1         3         0         2,02       
9  SUM     6         0         0         20
```

I would like to count the sum of individual rows of last columns until the word "SUM" appears in `df[0]` 
and then assign the result of this sum to the list.
For example:
First sum should be like: `Text1 row + Text2 + Text3` = `5,00 + 0,00 + 2,00` - sum of `df[:, -1]` in the preceding rows `df[0]=='SUM'`
and then the first element of the list is `['7,00']`
then the sum of the last column in the rows preceding the word `SUM` in `df[0]`:
`Text1+Text2+Text3+Text3` = `10+0+0+2,02`
and then the second element of the list is `['12,02']` and the whole list now looks like that: `['7,00'],['12,02']` or `['7,00','12,02']`

finally, I would like to compare the whole list with `df.loc[(df[0] == 'SUM')]`
Is such a counting of the sum under conditions possible from df?
Give me some hints or instructions how I can do it and whether it is possible at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
#convert last column to numbers
df.iloc[:, -1] = df.iloc[:, -1].str.replace(',','.').astype(float)

#create groups with last value SUM
df.insert(0, 'g', df[0].eq('SUM').iloc[::-1].cumsum().iloc[::-1])

#sum values per groups with omit last value (SUM)
df.insert(0, 'new', df.iloc[:, -1].groupby(df['g']).transform(lambda x: x[:-1].sum()))
print (df)
     new  g      0  1  2  3      4
2   7.00  2  Text1  1  1  5   5.00
3   7.00  2  Text2  8  4  0   0.00
4   7.00  2  Text3  1  3  0   2.00
5   7.00  2    SUM  6  0  0   7.00
6  12.02  1  Text1  1  1  0  10.00
7  12.02  1  Text2  8  4  0   0.00
8  12.02  1  Text3  1  3  0   0.00
8  12.02  1  Text4  1  3  0   2.02
9  12.02  1    SUM  6  0  0  20.00

#compare values 
df1 = df[df['new'].eq(df.iloc[:, -1]) & df[0].eq('SUM')]
print (df1)
   new  g    0  1  2  3    4
5  7.0  2  SUM  6  0  0  7.0
```

Comment: Great solution. Thank you for your help.
Now all I have to do is add:
`df1.loc[df['new'] == df.iloc[:, -1], 'Equal'] = 'True' 
df1.loc[df['new'] != df.iloc[:, -1], 'Equal'] = 'False' `

and I don't need to use any additional lists. Thank you again for your help. I'll analyze the code and use it in other cases.

Comment: @DeepSea - Or use `df['Equal'] = df['new'].eq(df.iloc[:, -1]) & df[0].eq('SUM')`